# Generate XML Output from Jasper Reports

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee, jasper-reports, report

Our team has integrated Jasper reports into a Spring MVC project to generate pdf/csv/html reports.  We have a requirement as well to generate XML output from our database for feeding into some other systems.  I was wondering if it is possible to use the Jasper reporting engine for this purpose as well (i.e. generate an XML output file as though its just another report format - tags etc. customised for our target schema), and also if it is possible, is it a sensible way to use the Jasper reporting engine.

thanks for replies

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You can use XML exporter for this purpose. You can use report templates (prepared in *iReport*, for example) or you can build dynamic report with Java API (JasperReports API or DynamicJasper API). Or you can prepare datasource with Java code and pass it to the report template with help of JR API. You can view [this samples](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference.html)

Comment: @AlexK can this be done even when the xml report outputted shouldd be based on a dynamic schema ? i think jasperreports generates this xml based on its own schema only. i asked a similar question-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25433279/dynamic-jasper-for-report-generation-when-schema-changes-dynamically